# Tomcat is runing, but cannot access it remotely

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, centos7, firewall

### Run Tomcat8 in centos7, Checked the tomcat status get following information:

```
[root@**** conf]# systemctl status tomcat
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat 8 Servlet Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-11-10 09:39:22 EST; 37min ago
  Process: 1013 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1102 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
           └─1102 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=o...

Nov 10 09:39:22 ****** systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat 8 Servlet Container...
Nov 10 09:39:22 ****** systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat 8 Servle
```

---

But when check the homepage of tomcat (http://***.***.***:8080), in Chrome,
Get the following information:

```
This page isn’t working

***.**.***.** didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

---

The centos 7 is with firewall and it running.

Thanks,

-Jimmy

Comment: is it not at all working? or it was working and currently it is not working?

Comment: it's a new Centos 7 server, I just installed tomcat in it.

Comment: Can you put the catalina.out last lines?

Comment: Try to turn off the firewall for a while and check if now works.

Comment: What interface is your Tomcat bound (`conf/server.xml` `Connector`'s address)? Should be the one, exposed externally (or simply `0.0.0.0`). Are you're trying to access it from the other machine? Do you have any proxies in front of it? Have you checked the firewall rules?

Comment: The lines of catalina.out:
10-Nov-2017 09:39:29.718 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8181"]
10-Nov-2017 09:39:29.726 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
10-Nov-2017 09:39:29.728 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1740 ms

Comment: There two connector's address:    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />           and    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />        is it the reason?